# unable to bind data to label inside repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

My code is like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptEvaluationInfo" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label runat="server" Id="lblCampCode" Text="<%#Eval("CampCode") %>"></asp:Label>

</ItemTemplate>
```

Everything looks okay to me, But it generates an error in the runtime. When I remove this part

```
Text="<%#Eval("CampCode") %>"
```

error goes.
SO I assume the issue is with databind. So I tried an alternative like this

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <label><%#Eval("CampCode") %> </label>

</ItemTemplate>
```

And it also works good. Can any one tell me what is the issue with my first code?

> Note: I don't have access to the error message due to the special
>   reasons  on my project , that's why I have not posted it here.
>   And I want to use ASP controls itself on the case that's why i haven't
>   gone with my second solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with quotes. Currently you have double quotes everywhere, so ASP.NET is not able to parse this. Change outer ones to single quotes like this:

```
Text='<%#Eval("CampCode") %>'
```